# CloudSql with Autoscaler access

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am stuck at one thing regarding CloudSQL.

I have my WordPress app running on GCE and I create Instance Group so I will utilise the AutoScaler.

for Db, I am using CloudSQL.

Now point where is stuck is the "Authorise network" in CloudSQL as it accepts only IPV4 Public IP.

How do I know when autoscaling happen what IP will attach to Instance so my instance will know where the DB is?

I can hard code the CloudSQL IP as a `CNAME` but from CloudSQL Side I am not able to figure it out how to provide access. I can make my DB access all open

If you can let me know what will be the point which I am missing.

I used cloudsql proxy also but that doesn't come with Service in Linux ... I hope you can understand my situation. Let me know if any idea you like to share on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way is to use the second generation instances and [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy), you’ll need to configure the Proxy on Linux and start it by using service account credentials as outlined at the provided link.

Another way is to use [startup](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) script in your GCE instance template, so you can get your new instance’s external IP address and add it to a Cloud SQL instance’s authorized networks by using [gcloud sql instance patch](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/instances/patch) command. The IP can be removed from the authorized networks in the same way by using [shutdown](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript) script. The external IP address of GCE VM instance can be retrieved from [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) by running:

`$ curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google".`

Comment: Read these articles about running [startup](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) and [shutdown](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript) scripts.

Comment: At [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) page you’ll find more information about retrieving instance metadata.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Better to include the additional information in the original answer rather than add comments.

Comment: Edited the answer.